# woocommerce brands plugin - moving page description

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Wondering if anyone knows the correct function hook to move the description on brand pages created with the official Brands Plugin.
http://www.woothemes.com/products/brands/

The function below works perfectly on product archive pages, but has no effect on brand archive pages.

```
//Move Product Category Description to Genesis after header
remove_action( 'woocommerce_archive_description', 'woocommerce_taxonomy_archive_description', 10 );
add_action( 'genesis_after_header', 'woocommerce_taxonomy_archive_description', 100 );
```

I've searched for hours but can't find the correct actions.

Guidance would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content', 'woocommerce_taxonomy_archive_description', 1, 5 );
```

Comment: If you could please explain what the code you're showing does, and why/how that code answers the question, it would make your answer even more helpful.